# Android location updates are too frequent contrary to documentation

Tags: android, android-gps, fusedlocationproviderapi, android-fusedlocation, google-location-services

I've been trying to wrap my head around all the new limitations that were introduced in Oreo regarding [background broadcasts](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#broadcasts) and [location updates](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits). I've cloned the [sample repo](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location) to play around with it, but it seems the actual behaviour does not match documentation.

I'm using the [PendingIntent implementation](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/LocationUpdatesPendingIntent), where the update interval is set to 60 seconds, with a batch delivery every 5 minutes. Instead I'm getting a location update every 2 minutes. As soon as the app starts, I request updates and then promptly kill the app. I don't have any apps running, my screen is on, I even disconnected the USB cord from it (in case USB debugging somehow requests locations too and the app's piggybacking off it).

I'm on a Pixel running Pie.

Anyone have an idea what could be going on?

Comment: can you show your fuseLocationApi implementation.

Comment: It's in the link to the repo. I didn't really change anything.